# Can someone explain me how does this javascript code works please?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Given a JavaScript function that takes in an array of numbers as the first and the only argument.

The function then removes one element from the array, upon removal, the sum of elements at odd indices is equal to the sum of elements at even indices. The function should count all the possible unique ways in which we can remove one element at a time to achieve balance between odd sum and even sum.

Example var arr = [2, 6, 4, 2];

Then the output should be 2 because, there are two elements 6 and 2 at indices 1 and 3 respectively that makes the combinations table.

When we remove 6 from the array

[2, 4, 2] the sum at odd indexes = sum at even indexes = 4

if we remove 2

[2, 6, 4] the sum at odd indices = sum at even indices = 6

The code below works perfectly. There might be other solutions but I want to understand this one, because I feel there is a concept I have to learn here. Can someone explain the logic of this algorithm please?

```
const arr = [2, 6, 4, 2];
const check = (arr = []) => {
  var oddTotal = 0;
  var evenTotal = 0;
  var result = 0;
  const arraySum = []
   for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
      if (i % 2 === 0) {
        evenTotal += arr[i];
        arraySum[i] = evenTotal
        
      } 
      else {
        oddTotal += arr[i];
        arraySum[i] = oddTotal
      } 
   }
   for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
      if (i % 2 === 0) {
         if (arraySum[i]*2 - arr[i] + oddTotal === (arraySum[i - 1] || 0)*2 + evenTotal) {
           result = result +1
          };
        } else if (arraySum[i]*2 - arr[i] + evenTotal === (arraySum[i - 1] || 0)*2 + oddTotal) {
          result = result +1
      }
   }
   return result;
};
```

Comment: The key is the `%` operator. Do you know what the remainder of a division is? Or are you familiar with the mathematical **mod** operation eg `12 mod 10`?

Comment: yes I know this, what I don't understand is this line  if (arraySum[i]*2 - arr[i] + oddTotal === (arraySum[i - 1] || 0)*2 + evenTotal) {
           result = result +1
          };

Comment: Run the loop on paper. It should tell you how the variables behave. That if is just testing if the difference between the double of this sum and this value plus odd total is the same as the previous sum plus even total. You can rename the variables to make more sense: `if (sumUpToCurrentValue*2 - currentValue + oddTotal === sumUpToPreviousValue*2 + evenTotal) ...`

Comment: Yea I see, thank you for your help, I think understanding why the *2 would help me